# Using a function to alter typedef fields when individual structs are identified using an array

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct, typedef

This seems to be a very specific question that I'm having trouble finding any sort of answer.

I'm attempting to use a typedef struct to store user information. Im using the format cust[x].firstName etc. to differentiate from one customer to another.  Since I'm defining this struct in the header, it's my understanding that by altering the fields of the struct inside a function, these changes should be reflected in main. However, this doesn't seem to be the case.

```
    typedef struct
 {
    char firstName[99];
    char lastName[99];
    int numOrders;
    char orders[99][99];
    float orderPrice[99][99];
    float orderNum[99][99];
 }Info;

int infoGet(FILE*,int);
int main()
{
int orderNum,i;
 FILE*input = fopen("input.txt","r");
 FILE*output = fopen("invoices.txt","w+");

fscanf(input,"%d",&orderNum);
Info cust[10];

infoGet(input,orderNum)
printf("%s %.2f %.2f\n",cust[0].orders,cust[0].orderPrice[1][0],cust[0].orderNum[1][0]);
}



int infoGet(FILE*input,int orderNum)
{
    int i,j;
    char space;
    Info cust[10];
    for(i = 0;i < orderNum;i++)
    {
        fscanf(input,"%s %s",cust[i].firstName,&cust[i].lastName);
        printf("%s %s\n",cust[i].firstName,cust[i].lastName);
        fscanf(input,"%d",&cust[i].numOrders);
        printf("This person has %d items to order\n",cust[i].numOrders);
        for(j=0;j < cust[i].numOrders;j++)
        {
            fscanf(input,"%s %f %f",cust[i].orders,&cust[i].orderPrice[1][j],&cust[i].orderNum[1][j]);
            printf("%s %.2f %.2f\n",cust[i].orders,cust[i].orderPrice[1][j],cust[i].orderNum[1][j]);
        }
    }
 }
```

The last printf statement in main should be printing what is scanned for in the last fscanf in the function, but it is not. Do I need to pass the struct into the function? or is their something else I need to do to keep this struct constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since I'm defining this struct in the header, it's my understanding that by altering the fields of the struct inside a function, these changes should be reflected in main.

This is a misunderstanding. The definition in the header defines a *type*. This is not an object that can be modified, but a definition that is needed by all code that creates and uses instances of that type. That is what happens in `main()` and `infoGet()`, where you instantiate arrays of `Info` objects with these statements:

```
Info cust[10]; // instantiates an array of 10 Info objects
```

Now, as to the actual problem: Your function `infoGet` has its own, *local* array `Info cust[10]`. Modifying it in the function has no effect outside of the function. You need to pass the array into the function from `main`. For example,

```
int infoGet(FILE*input, Info* cust, int orderNum)
{
    int i,j;
    char space;
    for(i = 0;i < orderNum;i++)
    {
    ....
}
```

and

```
int main()
{
  int orderNum,i;
  FILE*input = fopen("input.txt","r");
  FILE*output = fopen("invoices.txt","w+");

  fscanf(input,"%d",&orderNum);
  Info cust[10]; // Careful! What if orderNum is > 10?

  infoGet(input, cust, orderNum)
```

Note that you should check that `orderNum` isn't more than `10`, or allocate a variable length array:

```
  Info cust[orderNum];
```

Comment: This is exactly what was the problem. probably could have found the answer reading some docs